# How does Spotify/Discord automatically log you in (after the first time log-in), when they don't save the password locally?

Tags: authentication, spotify, discord, minecraft

I am trying to understand the concepts of how Spotify, Discord or Minecraft automatically log you in, after the first-time log-in, if they are not saving the password locally. Or are they saving the username and password locally with  encryption?

Comment: It's probably some kind of session token.  If it's in a web browser, it's probably cookies.  Your question presumes that a user name and a password is the only way to get in.  Note that most of us don't actually work on these programs, so we don't actually know what they are doing internally.  So any answer we provide would be speculation on our part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord safes a token locally, wich will be sent with API requests and is used to authenticate you. It first was stored in Local Storage, but now its hidden.

Minecraft uses a Session Token wich means Mojang will send you a token wich your client then sends to the Server to auth your account.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications would cache an encrypted token that was generated by sending off your username and password to their server. This token can be refreshed by sending it back to the server. This token can then be used to authenticate the user against any routes on the server.